# Multiply each letter in a string by its position in string (starting from 1) using only abstract list functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a string, I want to create a function that would multiply each letter in the string given its position in the string.

So for example, extend('cat') should produce 'caattt'.

I am only allowed to use abstract list functions: `list()`, `map()`, `filter()`, and `lambda` (recursion is allowed as well but no loops of any kind).

Code below is what I have tried, I'm trying to extract each letter as well as the position and work with those. Perhaps I do not understand how map and lambda work, but this is my approach.

```py
def extend(s):
  index = range(1, len(s) - 1)
  return list(map(lambda k: k*(lambda x: x, index), s))
```

Comment: How is this using recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the given string and a `range` object over `1` and the length of the string to a `lambda` function that returns a given character repeated by the given count:

```
def extend(s):
    return ''.join(map(lambda char, count: char * count, s, range(1, len(s) + 1)))
```

so that `extend('cat')` returns: `'caattt'`

Comment: This one seems to be most similar to what I was trying to do; thank you so much for your help! I was not aware you can use two parameters in lambda!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an optional parameter to keep track of the multiplier of the first character of the string for the current recursive call:

```
def extend(s, count=1):
    return s and s[0] * count + extend(s[1:], count + 1)
```

so that `extend('cat')` returns: `'caattt'`

Answer (score 0):

This might not meet your restrictions:

```
"".join([x*(i+1) for i,x in enumerate(s)])
```

Comment: The OP does say no loops of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that omits using `for` is to use `index` property of the string:

```
def extend(s):
    l = lambda x: x*(s.index(x) + 1)
    return "".join(map(l, list(s)))
```

For:

```
extend('cat`)
```

This outputs

```
caattt
```